# Delete records meeting criteria dacross tables

Tags: mysql, database

Long time lurker, first post(er?)

I need to delete some duplicate entries in my database based on attributes spread across multiple tables. This is the way I've done but, but I'm sure there is a better way (I'm by no means a SQL expert!). Any pointers would be great. (When I went to do this for a second time, it failed)

I'm first getting all the rows from a table, sorting by date, then picking the newest entry (dup1). Then I'm matching that list to another table based on a value (dup2). Then finally creating a list of rows based in their ID that appears in both tables (dup3). Then I want to delete from the main table where the ID is in the 3rd temp table.

**First, I created a temp table:**

```
create temporary table dup1
as
select * from
   (SELECT hex(media_id) as asset_id, folder_id, name, ingest_date
   FROM media
   order by ingest_date DESC) as dup
group by name having count(name)>1 and count(hex(folder_id))>1
```

**Then created a second temp table:**

```
create temporary table dup2
as
SELECT hex(asset_id) as asset_id, value FROM datavalues where name_id = 103 group by value having count(value)>1;
as
SELECT hex(asset_id), value FROM datavalues where name_id = 103 group by value having count(value)>1;
```

**Created a final temp table that merges the two previous temp tables**

```
create temporary table dup3
as
select dup1.asset_id from dup1
join dup2 on dup2.asset_id = dup1.asset_id
```

**Then deleted all assets from the media table that exist in dup3**

```
DELETE FROM media where hex(media_id) in (SELECT * from dup3);
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you  using? mysql <> sql server. And that final delete looks problematic. At least in sql server that will fail if dup3 has more than 1 column. Use joins instead brittle code.

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server.

Comment: what 's your question  .. you have error  ?   .. show error message  ,.. wrong resul ?  .. add  a  proper data sample you actual result and the expected  result